# Why Grid component of Material UI has different components implemented with different propTypes based on environment

Tags: material-ui

After hours of debugging and looking through the docs, I found out that `<Grid />` component in Material UI has different version of its implementation base on `process.env.NODE_ENV`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const requireProp = requirePropFactory('Grid');
  StyledGrid.propTypes = {
    ...StyledGrid.propTypes,
    alignContent: requireProp('container'),
    alignItems: requireProp('container'),
    direction: requireProp('container'),
    justify: requireProp('container'),
    lg: requireProp('item'),
    md: requireProp('item'),
    sm: requireProp('item'),
    spacing: requireProp('container'),
    wrap: requireProp('container'),
    xs: requireProp('item'),
    zeroMinWidth: requireProp('zeroMinWidth'),
  };
}
```

Wondering if someone from the team or who have contributed to the project could explain the reason behind this decision. Cheers!